# vba to concatenate cells and keep bold formatting

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

I looked for several hours for a satisfactory answer to this question and couldn't find one, so I rolled my own.

For example, suppose cell A1 = "word1", A2 = "**word2**", A3 = "word3", and A4 = "word4."

I want B1 to be "word1 **word2** word3 word4 "

If none, any, or all the words in column A are bold, I want that reflected in B1. Like this:

[partial sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px5fL.png)

```
Sub test1()

Dim Row As Integer
Dim Start As Integer
Dim Length As Integer

        ' concatenate the words with a space between each
    Range("B1").Value = ""
    For Row = 1 To 4
        Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value & " " & Cells(Row, "A").Value
    Next Row

        ' match bold formatting
    Start = 1
    For Row = 1 To 4
        Length = Len(Cells(Row, "A").Value)
        Range("B1").Characters(Start, Length + 1).Font.Bold = Cells(Row, "A").Font.Bold
        Start = Start + Length + 1
    Next Row

End Sub
```

I found I needed two separate loops to make this work. With one loop, Excel made bold all the words following the first bold one, except the last word if it was not bold.

Why did I need (Start, Length + 1) in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an exact answer but maybe can provide you ideas:

```
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=13, Length:=6).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
End With
```

You need to find how to set your Start and Length values using the functions that fit your needs.

The usage of `Length + 1` makes that select all the text in your cell before Start.